# RegEx Return part of a String

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of musicians and songs in a single string that i need seperated. Each string contains a dash (-); however the artist name may also include a dash (-).

Examples

```
   Lil Wayne - Drop It Like Its Hot
   T-Pain - Bring the Heat
```

How do i write two regular expressions to

```
 1) Return text before the furthest dash (-) 
 2) Return text after the furthest dash (-)
```

Comment: If the dash can be everywhere, there's no way. You can try to split the string at the first dash with spaces around.

Comment: Well, you may try `'~^(.*)-(.*)$~'`. However, looking at the examples, I think you might want  `preg_match('~^(.*)\s+-\s+(.*)$~', $s, $results)`.

Comment: Are you building the list?

Comment: Chris i am extracting the names using importio.

Comment: I would step back and work on building the data in a parseable format. Use something for encapsulating, then use a delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mario, you can use the built-in regex function `preg_split` to split the entry into an array first:

```
$artist = "Lil Wayne - Drop It Like Its Hot";
$keywords = preg_split("/\-+/", $artist);
```

Once you have the array, you can re-assemble the content based on the requirements:

1) Return text before furthest dash (-)

```
$name = "";
for($x = 0; $x < count($keywords)-1; $x++) {
  if ($x ==0) {
    $name .= $keywords[$x];
  } else {
    $name = $name . "-" . $keywords[$x];
  }
}
```

2) Return text after the furthest dash (-)

```
$arrlength = count($keywords)
$description = $keywords[$arrlength-1]
```

Comment: Why `$name += $x;`? Also `$keywords[$arrlength]` is not going to match up because `count($keywords)` is the number of elements (3), not the indices (2). or rather that'd be for the `t-pain` example. I guess it works for `lil wayne` one

Comment: You are right the string operator should be .= instead of +=. Also there is 1 off since array index start at 0. I make the changes to my original post. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use the `explode()` function. Then theres no need for Regex.

```
$x = explode ("-", $string);
```

You will get the array $x. In wich $x[0] would be the first and $x[1] the second part.

**edit**
So for the 't-pain' case you should use another delimiter:

```
$x = explode (" - ", $string);
```

Comment: OP wants to split on `-`s, not join.

Comment: What would it be for `T-Pain - Bring the Heat`, huh?

Comment: That won't solve the issue about the triple, or more, hyphenated names; e.g. `T-Pain - Bring the Heat`

Comment: What about my edit?

Comment: Not really a solution you can build with. The question isn't really answerable because there could be any amount of `-`s and you aren't going to know which one is the artist/song. An example `Herbie Hancock- Rockit - Live - November -1983`..